# Metric space, inequation

Tags: functions, metric-spaces

I have a question to the following problem:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metrical space and let be $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ twice differentiable with $f(0)=0$, $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, $f'\geq 0$ and $f''\leq 0$

Proof that $f(a+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b\geq 0$

Conclude that

$d_f:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}$

$(x,y)\mapsto f(d(x,y))$

defines a metric space on X.

__

My problem ist to show that $f(a+b)\leq f(a)+f(b)$.
Could someone help me with that?

I tried it with the mean value theorem and the inequation for convex functions, but nothing worked for me. :(

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $f'$ is decreasing, and being convex is equivalent to having to having for all $x<y<z$, $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \leq \frac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}$. Then use the mean value thoerem.

Comment: Right, we proofed that. But I do not see how I have to use the mean value theorem now.

Comment: Using the mean value theorem, the quantity on the left (in my comment) is equal to $f'(c_1)$ for some $x<c_1<y$, and the one on the right is equal to $f'(c_2)$ for some $y<c_2<z$.

Answer (score 1):

The property $f(a+b)\le f(a)+f(b)$ is called subadditivity. The problem is to show that an increasing concave function with $f(0)=0$ is subadditive.

If we rewrite the inequality as 
$$
f(a+b)-f(a) \le f(b)-f(0)
$$
it takes the form of "the function $g(x) = f(x+b)-f(x)$ is decreasing". Which is easy to check by looking at its derivative: 
$$
g'(x) = f'(x+b)-f'(x) \le 0
$$ 
since $f''\le 0$.

The above proof  does not actually need $f$ to be twice differentiable. Knowing that $f'$ is decreasing is enough.